# Column NOT NULL but script is still creating a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a script, which I use to INSERT data to my database. In HTML I have multiple textboxes. If data is entered into the textbox my script is running the INSERT statement. My script is also running the INSERT statement if there is no data entered into the textbox.

If there is no data entered into the textbox, the script creates an empty row in the database. I have tried to block this by changing the column to NOT NULL.

But it seems to be not working.

Does someone know the reason for that and how I can solve it?

**Edit 1:**

```
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='" . $id1 . "' AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['USER_ID'] . "'";

        $result1 = $link->query($sql1);
        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

            $sql11 = "UPDATE product SET voorraad = quantity -" . $quantity . " WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['USER_ID'] . "' AND id='" . $id1 . "'";

            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql11)){

                echo '<p>product1 is updated</p><br />';

            } else {

                echo '<p>error</p>';

            }
        } else {
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO product(user_id, name, price, tax) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query1);
            $exec1 = $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['USER_ID'], $name1, $price1, $tax1));

            if($exec1){

                echo '<p>product1 is created</p>';  

            } else {
                echo '<p>error</p>';
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well it would be quite useful to **see your script** (_we are not clairvoyant_) rather than just have a commentary on what it may or may not do i.e. a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you checking in php whether the checkbox is checked? can you show us the relevant code.

Comment: A value of '' (an empty string) is not the same as null.  Null literally means not set.  You may want to check if the text != '' before allowing it (if that's what you want)

Comment: See edit 1 in my first post

Comment: I am not checking in PHP. Isnt it possible to block this just in phpmyadmin?

Comment: You could use `<input pattern=".{1,}"   required title="Min 1 characters">` on the field to force some entry.

Comment: @NigelRen. No. In my case the textboxes may be empty. I just dont want to send the empty textboxes to the database if there is no data entered

Comment: Are you talking about in the UPDATE or the INSERT now? PS: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP, it is not a database. MySQL is your database

Comment: I am talking about the INSERT (in the UPDATE will not be executed if there is no data)

Comment: Hi John, I think there is some confusion here. You state you are creating empty rows due to no text being input on a form? So basically you don't want to create a row (perform an insert) when these fields are empty? Is this a form where you can press Submit when everything is empty?

Comment: The original script is larger than the example above. You cant press submit when everything is empty. But for this part YES (the products part) the user can press on submit when no product data is empty.

Comment: still not fixed

Comment: and why do I get downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting empty strings, and empty string are not NULL, to check for NULL error do:

INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
and you will see error. The NOT NULL checks only for values that are not NULL.

To prevent empty string either you have to use triggers, or do the checks on server side programming language to convert empty strings to NULL before performing INSERT query. An example trigger for INSERT may be like: (this is just an example)

CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty
    BEFORE INSERT ON addresses
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF street = '' THEN SET street = NULL END IF;
END;

Comment: Is this for the UPDATE or INSERT statement?

Comment: For insert statement only

Answer (score -1):

you can verify variables and execute query if variable is not null & empty ,else write values are null, must pass data

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: No, that is not what I need. The textbox may be empty